# Disable buildifier warnings on VSCode bazel files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, bazel

I'm using VSCode with the Bazel extension, and the warnings are pretty distracting.

I know I can disable them by adding comments to the file, but I don't want to impact other developers, just tell my own VSCode install to stop bothering me about warning.

How can I configure that? I couldn't find anything in the Bazel extension settings.

Comment: Neither the args in the settings nor the .buildifier.json in the directory seem to be configurable, I found a issue https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel/issues/208

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/blob/master/buildifier/README.md

> or by modifying the default warnings set by using + or - modifiers before each warning category:
>
> `buildifier --lint=warn --warnings=-positional-args,+unsorted-dict-items`

But vscode-bazel does not pass the args in the settings to the linter. And not recognized the `.buildifier.json`

so i create a wrapper binary in a hack way

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/buildifier $* --warnings=-module-docstring
```